# jQuery ajaxSend not triggered in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to intercept ajax calls for testing pusposes using the following code:

```
function(callback){
  $(document).on("ajaxSend", function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
    $(document).off("ajaxSend");
    jqxhr.abort();
    callback(settings);
  }); 
}
```

It will intercept the request, abort it and call a callback.

I have tried the "ajaxStart" event, this does get triggered, but I require the settings for my tests.

All this code is working for Chrome and Firefox, but for IE8 the events doesn't get triggered.

Comment: have you tried  `$(selector).ajaxSend( callback )` and `$("#stage1").ajaxStart( callback)` instead of calling them from `on()`  ?

Comment: Yes, this was my original implementation, same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason why my test was not working on IE.

Even though my AJAX request was aborted, IE had problems with calling the dummy URL I had passed in for my test.

I had passed in `$.get("http://localhost")` whereas my application is hosted on  `localhost:8008`.

Updating the get method to `$.get(window.location.href)` has fixed the issue.